# Global keyevent logger for application in android

Tags: android

I have a class an activity class as follows:

`public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {}`

The whole class is significantly long that have some good depth of views(mainly webview). I am trying to implement a global keyevent logger for this class. I tried to set keylistener for main view but cannot set it because I think I have not extended the OnKeyListener Class? The error I get is

```
The method is the type view is not applicable for MyActivity
```

I also have overridden OnKeyDown Method which does not collect any data:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i("Key Pressed: ", keyCode+" = number");
}
```

So, what way should I go to grab all keyevent happening inside my activity? I am pretty much clueless at the moment. I really appreciate your help.

EDIT:
I am looking for all soft keyboard events only. (Sorry I forgot to mention that...)

Answer (score 0):

ok I see . u want to know which character they typed .
if they type a.b.or c. u want to know that they typed a.b.or c.
when u use SearchVIew .u can set a listener with the character changed.
so I think u can follow this way.

- u want know the user typed ,so u must receive the user type.
  may be u need something like a EditText.
  see the TextView source code(as EditText extend TextView and EditText and the TextView do the most thing to handle the InputMethodManager)
- then set a listener about the character changed .
- this way I think u will know which kind of character will be typed

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that. But I am looking for soft keyboard events only.

Comment: soft keyboard? the input word? if i type a.b.or c. u want to know that I typed a.b.or c? am i right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I want to know the typed character from the soft keyboard.

Comment: I was able to implement this to EditText but I cannot do the same for WebView... Is there different procedure for doing this in case of WebView?